# How-to validate user input when using scanner for input gathering

Tags: java

### Description

What I am aiming to do is request user to provide an input only to those entries which triggered an exception excluding those input requests which have been satisfactory

### Example

*Note*: `input` is an instance of a `Scanner`

```
public Fluid addFluid() {
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("Please enter fluids ID: "); 
            f.setFluidID(input.next());
            System.out.println("Please enter fluids molecular weight: ");   
            f.setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble()); 
            System.out.println("Please enter fluids temperature: ");            
            f.setTemperature(input.nextDouble());
            error = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
           // if exception happens on input for setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble()); skip print statement for fluids ID and f.setFluidID(input.next());
        }
    }
    while(error != false);
    getFluid().add(f);
    System.out.println(getFluid());
    return f;
}
```

### Output

```
Please enter fluids ID: 
propane
Please enter fluids molecular weight: 
a
Error! Please provide the right input.
Please enter fluids ID:                // how to exclude this print statement
Please enter fluids molecular weight:
```

Would there be a way how to do this using an `if / else` structure. I would want to avoid doing `try / catch` for every input operator. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer:

You'll need clear the buffer on the Scanner after the call to `nextDouble()`, since your `InputStream` will contain a newline `\n`.

**Adding `input.next();` or `input.nextLine();` to the end of your `catch` blocks should work to skip that extra `\n`.**

*(See [java.util.Scanner : why my nextDouble() does not prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374698/873263))*

### Explanation:

- Even though `nextDouble` blocks execution until the user enters a newline `\n`, it only returns characters from `Scanner`'s buffer that are valid characters (characters that will parse correctly to a `double`). This means
- if you enter input that doesn't parse to a `double`, those invalid characters are still sitting in the buffer. When you attempt to read the `nextDouble` again, it will just repeat the same process on the existing input, resulting in the infinite loop.
- Therefore, you'll need to "clear" the buffer before continuing. Since there doesn't seem to be a method for this, you'll just need to advance the Scanner to the end of the buffer. In this case, `input.next();` will suffice.

*(Credits to user [jonhopkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053938/jonhopkins%5D) for the code I shamelessly grabbed from [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146259/873263))*

```
System.out.println("Please enter fluids ID: ");
while (true) {
    try {
        f.setFluidID(input.next());
        break; // break out of the current loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
        input.next();
    }
}

System.out.println("Please enter fluids molecular weight: ");
while (true) {
    try {
        f.setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble());
        break; // break out of the current loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
        input.next();
    }
}

System.out.println("Please enter fluids temperature: ");
while (true) {
    try {
        f.setTemperature(input.nextDouble());
        break; // break out of the current loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
        input.next();
    }
}
```

*NOTE: You may even need an extra `input.next()` call before you read the 2nd and 3rd inputs (I haven't tested this).*

Comment: Very nice answer. I never knew that was an issue, hence the confusion about my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Simply place it outside your loop:

```
public Fluid addFluid() {
    System.out.println("Please enter fluids ID: "); 
    f.setFluidID(input.next());

    do{
        try{    
            System.out.println("Please enter fluids molecular weight: ");   
            f.setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble()); 
            System.out.println("Please enter fluids temperature: ");            
            f.setTemperature(input.nextDouble());
            error = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
           // if exception happens on input for setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble()); skip print statement for fluids ID and f.setFluidID(input.next());
        }
    }
    while(error != false);
    getFluid().add(f);
    System.out.println(getFluid());
    return f;
}
```

Now it will only print it once while the other input can be repeated.
If you want to check for individual problems with the molecular weight and fluids temperature, you'll have to repeat the try-catch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however that wouldn't be sufficient enough. The reason for that is - I want the program to check for invalid input for all input fields. That applies to when setting fluidID as well.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic: in that case you will need multiple `while` loops.

Comment: Agree, it looks like there is no better way.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but should work:

```
public Fluid addFluid() {
    boolean alreadyAnswered1 = false;
    boolean alreadyAnswered2 = false;
    boolean alreadyAnswered3 = false;
    do{
        try{
            if (!alreadyAnswered1) {
                System.out.println("Please enter fluids ID: ");
                 f.setFluidID(input.next());
                 alreadyAnswered1 = true;
            }
            if (!alreadyAnswered2) {
                System.out.println("Please enter fluids molecular weight: ");
                f.setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble());
                alreadyAnswered2 = true;
            }
            if (!alreadyAnswered3) {
                System.out.println("Please enter fluids temperature: ");
                f.setTemperature(input.nextDouble());
                alreadyAnswered3 = true;
            }
            error = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
           // if exception happens on input for setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble()); skip print statement for fluids ID and f.setFluidID(input.next());
        }
    }
    while(error != false);
    getFluid().add(f);
    System.out.println(getFluid());
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Because it will print out the required inputs to the console.

Comment: @bary thank you for your answer. It works this way as well, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to repeat the request for input for whichever ones where an exception is thrown. I would just use a few smaller loops, each with their own separate `try-catch` blocks.

```
System.out.println("Please enter fluids ID: ");
while (true) {
    try {
        f.setFluidID(input.next());
        break; // break out of the current loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
    }
}

System.out.println("Please enter fluids molecular weight: ");
while (true) {
    try {
        f.setMolecularWeight(input.nextDouble());
        break; // break out of the current loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
    }
}

System.out.println("Please enter fluids temperature: ");
while (true) {
    try {
        f.setTemperature(input.nextDouble());
        break; // break out of the current loop
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Error! Please provide the right input.");
    }
}
```

This will cause the program to loop for each input until no exception is thrown for that input. It also removes the need for an outer loop that keeps going until `error == false`. If you want the input prompts to be displayed again after the error message, simply put the prompts inside their respective `while` loops.

Comment: This was the way I had in mind, although I was hoping I could avoid doing try/catch for individual fields. Thank you for your answer, if nothing else will come up I will choose it as the answer for this question.

Comment: I can understand wanting to avoid it. I'm not entirely sure if it is possible though, aside from something like @bary's answer, so I'd be interested to see if a better answer comes up too.

Comment: I've looked up on-line for an answer, but wasn't successful with regards to my question.
 Jon the code sample you've provided ends up in an infinite loop.

Comment: An infinite loop? Is the `break` leaving the `try` instead of the `while`? If that's the case, I would just use a flag that is set after the input to get out of the `while` loop.

Comment: I moved this code out of the original `do { } while(error != false);` by the way. I don't know if you left it in there, which could be a cause of the problem.

Comment: I am just working to fix it. I will update when I am done. @jonhopkins